# setting the chances of occurrence of elements in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

For example I have 3 elements in an array:

```
public function randomTile():Number

{

var tiles:Array = new Array(fire,ice,water);

var index:Number=Math.floor(Math.random()*tiles.length);

return tiles[index];

}
```

How to set the chances of occurrence of fire(70%), ice(10%), and water(20%)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any number of elements and you can specify any chance value.

```
var tiles:Array = [
  {"item":"fire", "chance":70 },
  {"item":"ice",  "chance":10 },
  {"item":"water","chance":20}
];

var picked:Object = pickRandomByChance(tiles);
trace(picked.item);

public function pickRandomByChance(options:Array):Object
{
  var copy:Array = [];
  var range:Number = 0;
  for (var i:int = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
  {
    copy.push( { "item":options[i].item, "chance":options[i].chance } );
    range += copy[i].chance;
    if (i > 0)
      copy[i].chance += copy[i - 1].chance;
  }

  var pick:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * range);

  for (i = 0; i < copy.length; i++)
  {
    if (pick <= copy[i].chance)
      return copy[i];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Won't this always return 'fire' or null as the loop always checks 'fire' first and 10 and 20 are in the <=70 range?

Comment: There is an error in trace(picked.item) access undefined property "picked". How to get rid of this?

Comment: Did you declare picked? Make sure it is declared as a class member or inside a function before you access it.

Comment: It's working now. The problem now is that the "water" appears more than the "fire". I think the chances of occurrence reversed. I don't know why.

Comment: Updated the answer, the slice wasn't making a deep copy of the array, so the original values were changing and causing water to come up all the time.

Answer (score 1):

There quite a few ways you could do this, and it largely depends of the scope of your project.  If you just have the three elements, using a switch statement would be easy:

```
var rand:Number = Math.random();
switch(true){
    case rand >= .3:
        //use fire
        break;

    case rand >= .1
        //use water
        break;

    default:
        //use ice
}
```

Someone else may have a better way though